# How can I invoke a Java program from Perl?

Tags: java, perl

I'm new with Perl and I'm trying to do something and can't find the answer.

I created a Java project that contains a main class that gets several input parameters.

I want to wrap my Java with Perl:  I want to create a Perl script that gets the input parameters, and then passes them to the Java program, and runs it.

For example:

If my main is called `mymain`, and I call it like this: `mymain 3 4 hi` (`3`, `4` and `hi` are the input parameters), I want to create a Perl program called `myperl` which when it is invoked as `myperl 3 4 hi` will pass the arguments to the Java program and run it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Running a Java program is just like running any other external program.

Your question has two parts :

1. How do I get the arguments from Perl to the Java program?
2. How do I run the program in Perl?

For (1) you can do something like

```
my $javaArgs = " -cp /path/to/classpath -Xmx256";
my $className = myJavaMainClass;
my $javaCmd = "java ". $javaArgs ." " . $className . " " . join(' ', @ARGV);
```

Notice the `join()` function - it will put all your arguments to the Perl program and separate them with space.

For (2) you can follow @AurA 's answer.

- Using the `system()` function

  ```
  my $ret = system("$javaCmd");
  ```

This will not capture (i.e. put in the variable `$ret`) the output of your command, just the return code, like `0` for success.

- Using backticks

  ```
  my $out = `$javaCmd`;
  ```

This will populate $out with the whole output of the Java program ( you may not want this ).

- Using pipes

  ```
  open(FILE, "-|", "$javaCmd");
  my @out = <FILE>
  ```

This is more complicated but allows more operations on the output.

For more information on this see [perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Comment: Running java calling perl script on a windows machine: process = r.exec("cmd /c perl D:\\perlexamples\\hello.pl");\

Answer (score 1):

```
$javaoutput = `java javaprogram`;
or
system "java javaprogram";
```

For a jar file

```
$javaoutput = `java -jar filename.jar`;
or
system "java -jar filename.jar";
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply;

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, now i/m getting: Error: Could not find or load main class dbtools.jar

Comment: You probably need to set the classpath. Try to run the java program outside first and then use the same syntax inside.